# Form validation linking to different page in flask

Tags: forms, validation, redirect, flask

Hello I am trying to create a simple survey app where if you complete the form it moves you on to a page where you can view the results of your survey.

The current problem that I am having is this "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

Sever.py:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, session, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'very secret'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    if len(request.form['name']) < 1 or len(request.form['comments']) < 1:
        flash("you need to fill out the name and comments")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('createUser'))
    return redirect('/')


@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def createUser():
    return render_template('results.html', name=request.form['name'],
        location=request.form['location'],  favLang=request.form['favLang'],
    comments=request.form['comments'])
    return redirect('/')

app.run(debug=True)
```

The if/else statment works becuase i get my flash when i dont enter a name or comment. I just can't get the else to go to the app.route('/results') properly. I also tried it with this with no success:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    if len(request.form['name']) < 1 or len(request.form['comments']) < 1:
        flash("you need to fill out the name and comments")
    else:
        return redirect('/results')
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the comment from @davidism i just created the user in the vaidation form and then linked on the results page.

here it is:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    if len(request.form['name']) < 1 or len(request.form['comments']) < 1:
        flash("you need to fill out the name and comments")
    else:
        return render_template('results.html', name=request.form['name'],
            location=request.form['location'],  favLang=request.form['favLang'],
            comments=request.form['comments'])
    return redirect('/')
```

I dont know how "correct" it is but i certianly works the way i wanted it to.